# Eliminar registro validando 2 campos php

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

estoy realizando una aplicación web de reserva de horas, en la cual voy por la parte de ANULAR. La anulación la quiero realizar validando 2 campos, el rut y el numero de reserva. No se como realizar la consulta o el código que debo utilizar en php para que valide esos 2 campos antes de anular o eliminar la reserva, el código que tengo es el siguiente.
index:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex mt-4 margin-left mx-auto border shadow" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="200" style="text-align:center; border: solid 5px;">
        <div class="icon-box iconbox-red col-12" style="padding:15px 15px 15px 15px">

          <div class=" center">
            <img src="assets/img/cancelar.png" alt="" width="50px">
          </div>
          <br>
          <h4>Anular Hora</h4>
          <h6>Accede con tu RUT y número de reserva</h6>
          <br>
          <form action="anular.php" method="POST">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="rut" id="rut" onkeyup="mascara(this,formatoRUT)" maxlength="12" required placeholder="Ingrese su RUT">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nreserva" id="nreserva" placeholder="Ingrese N° de reserva" style="margin-top:10px">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="btn-valida-rut" id="btn-valida-rut" class="btn btn-danger">Buscar</button>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
```

y el action es el siguiente:

```
<?php include 'php/conexion.php';?>
<?php 
$rut = $_POST['rut'];
$nreserva = $_POST['nreserva'];

$query=("SELECT*FROM datos WHERE id =$nreserva and rut = $rut");

$consulta=pg_query($conexion,$query) or die ('Hubo un error en la consulta.');
if(pg_num_rows($consulta)<1){
    echo 'La reserva asociada al rut '.$rut. 'no existe' ;
} else {
    $query = ("DELETE FROM datos WHERE id = $nreserva and rut = $rut");
    $consulta=pg_query($conexion, $query) or die ('Hubo un error en la consulta.').pg_last_error();
    echo 'La reserva con numero '.$nreserva.' ha sido anulada';
}
?>
```

hasta ahi quede ya que no supe como seguir, espero me puedan guiar con alguna indicación

Comment: Porque tienes dos queries cuando puedes hacerlo en uno solo? Con un SELECT * FROM datos d WHERE d.id = '$nreserva' AND d.rut = '$rut'; cumples la condición para ambos campos donde el id y el rut sean los ingresados por el usuario.

Comment: yo veo todo bien, cual es el problema?

Comment: @John me da el siguiente error al darle a buscar,
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\OnePage\anular.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\OnePage\anular.php on line 8

Comment: @AndresGonzalez debes instalar o habilitar el postgres en tu xamp pus por default vienen solo con mysql
  https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.setup.php  no se que version esta usando pero te dejo el video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFvBnsY15Bo

Comment: consulta @john , se puede realizar lo mismo pero solo con mysql o es 100% necesario instalar postgres??

Comment: Si tu bd está hecha en postgres deberás usar postgres, si usas mysql pues haces todo en mysql. pg_query es de postgress, puedes usar mysql pero deberas cambiar el motor de bd a mysql

Comment: @AndresGonzalez eso depende de tu proyecto, la base es lo que tu estes usando ya sea postgresql o mysql tu decides, si estas comensando te recomiendo mysql que es mas flexible y rapida de aprender

Comment: @John Vi un tutorial donde aparecia pg_query y las demas pg pero yo estoy usando mysql  cuales serian sus equivalentes en esta bd ?

Comment: @AndresGonzalez usa el manual https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php si buscas en el manual encontraras las equivalentes, como se usan, y ejemplos